# How can I use qmake to copy files recursively

Tags: qmake

In my source tree I have a bunch of resources, I want to copy them with make install to my defined target path. Since the resource tree has many, many subdirectories, I want qmake to find all files recursively.

I tried:

```
   resources.path = /target/path
   resources.files += `find /path/to/resources`
   INSTALLS += resources
```

and:

```
    resources.path = /target/path
    resources.files += /path/to/resources/*
    resources.files += /path/to/resources/*/*
    resources.files += /path/to/resources/*/*/*
    resources.files += /path/to/resources/*/*/*/*
    INSTALLS += resources
```

Both don't have the result I was hoping for.

Answer (score 4):

I have done it like this:

```
res.path = $$OUT_PWD/targetfolder
res.files = sourcefolder

INSTALLS += res
```

this would copy `"wherever this qmake script is"/sourcefolder` into `buildfolder/"same sub folder on build dir"/targetfolder`

so you would have `targetfolder/sourcefolder/"all other subfolders and files..."`

Example:

```
#(My .pro file's dir) $$PWD = /mysources/
#(My Build dir)       $$OUT_PWD = /project_build/


extras.path = $$OUT_PWD
extras.files += extras
src.path = $$OUT_PWD
src.files += src

INSTALLS += extras src
```

Would copy `/mysources/extras` to `/project_build/extras` and `/mysources/src` to `/project_build/src`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that directories are installed with 'cp -r -f', so this does the trick:

```
resources.path = /target/path
resources.files += /path/to/resources/dir1
resources.files += /path/to/resources/dir2
resources.files += /path/to/resources/dir3 
resources.files += /path/to/resources/dirn # and so on...
resources.files += /path/to/resources/*    # don't forget the files in the root
INSTALLS += resources
```

Comment: Have you tried using the replace function [files()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false) to enumerate the files? `$$files(/path/to/resources/*, true)` returns all the files recursively in `/path/to/resources`.